# is it Possible to set variable inside a View in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to set a variable in Sql Server that is selecting date from a view the query I am using is

```
declare @var varchar(20)
set @var = (SELECT Current_Period_SID FROM dbo.VW_Current_Period_SID_USNT)
```

just wondering is there a way to set variable in a view something like

```
CREATE VIEW mp_test AS
declare @var varchar(20)

set @var = (SELECT Current_Period_SID FROM dbo.VW_Current_Period_SID_USNT)

GO
```

Doing this gives Error

Comment: You can write a function to set a variable and return it. Using a view is no the correct method.

Comment: It should also be noted that if your subquery returns more than one value you will receive another error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will do this as a function then

Comment: Be very careful here. It seems you have a lot of views in your system. This in itself is no problem but you also seem to be willing to nest views. This IS a problem, and a major one at that. Nesting views is a sure fire way to get horrible execution plans. As a result your queries will be very slow. Check out this article. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/ Make sure to look at the section about nested views.

Comment: Thank you this article is helpful, yes I have nested views and queries are slow. I am trying to tweak it now

Comment: It seems so logical to nest views but it is better for performance to rewrite the underlying queries in each view. Kind of sucks but it is the reality of sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can't do that in a view.  I'm not even sure what the point of the above view would be since it doesn't return any value.  Even if you could, you wouldn't want to.  A variable like this can only store one varchar(20) value.  Without an "order by" and top statement you would either get an error or a non-deterministic value unless your table happens to only have a single record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will do it as a function then

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fake a variable in your view using CTE. You can test-run it in your version of SQL Server.

```
CREATE VIEW vwImportant_Users AS
WITH params AS (
    SELECT 
    varType='%Admin%', 
    varMinStatus=1)
SELECT status, name 
    FROM sys.sysusers, params
    WHERE status > varMinStatus OR name LIKE varType

SELECT * FROM vwImportant_Users
```

yielding output:

```
status  name
12      dbo
0       db_accessadmin
0       db_securityadmin
0       db_ddladmin
```

also via `JOIN`

```
WITH params AS ( SELECT varType='%Admin%', varMinStatus=1)
SELECT status, name 
    FROM sys.sysusers INNER JOIN params ON 1=1
    WHERE status > varMinStatus OR name LIKE varType
```

also via `CROSS APPLY`

```
WITH params AS ( SELECT varType='%Admin%', varMinStatus=1)
SELECT status, name 
    FROM sys.sysusers CROSS APPLY params
    WHERE status > varMinStatus OR name LIKE varType
```